# 2nd moment of the Beta Function / Beta function simplification

Tags: statistics, beta-function

Let $B(x,y)$ denote the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

I have $$\frac{B(x+2, y)}{B(x, y)}$$
Wikipedia says $$B(x+1, y) = B(x, y) \cdot \frac {x}{x+y}$$
Thus,
$$\frac{B(x+2, y)}{B(x, y)}$$ should equal $$\frac {x^2}{(x+y)^2}$$
But I am told by a computer and my source material that I am wrong.
Have I just made simple mistake?

For context, I am attempting to find the 2nd moment of the [Beta Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). I am aware of the derivation involving the gamma function, but I just wanted to see where this went.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the formula to $B(x+2,y)$, you have to replace $x$ with $x+1$. Hence

$$B(x+2,y)=B(x+1,y)\frac{x+1}{x+1+y}=B(x,y)\frac{x}{x+y}\frac{x+1}{x+1+y}$$

Comment: I'm a complete idiot! Thanks -_-

Comment: Will accept in a few